# ClientBuildManager throws AspNetHostingPermission exception

Tags: code-access-security, aspnet-compiler

I'm having a weird error when trying to create an instance of ClientBuildManager.

Here is the code that throws the exception:

```cs
public class createTest
{
    public string test()
    {
        var maxLineLength = 80;
        var invalidVirtualPathChars = new char[] { '*', '?'};
        PrecompilationFlags _precompilationFlags = new PrecompilationFlags();
        string _keyFile = null;
        string _keyContainer = null; 
        var _sourceVirtualDir = "/";
        var _sourcePhysicalDir = @"C:\O2\_XRules_Local\_localAspPoCs_2";
        var _targetPhysicalDir = @"C:\O2\_XRules_Local\_localAspPoCs_2_Compiled".createDir();

        var clientBuildManagerParameter = new ClientBuildManagerParameter();

        clientBuildManagerParameter.PrecompilationFlags = _precompilationFlags;
        clientBuildManagerParameter.StrongNameKeyFile = _keyFile;
        clientBuildManagerParameter.StrongNameKeyContainer = _keyContainer;
        var _client = new ClientBuildManager(_sourceVirtualDir, 
            _sourcePhysicalDir,
            _targetPhysicalDir, 
            clientBuildManagerParameter);

        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Here are the stack traces:

```
  Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
  [1:19:21 PM] ERROR:      InnerException:    at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.EnsureHostCreated()
  at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.get_CodeGenDir()
  at O2.Script.createTest.test() in c:\_WorkDir\SI\O2_Scripts\temp\compiler_callback.cs:line 45
  at DynamicType.dynamicMethod()  StackTrace:
```

and

```
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
  at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
  at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObjectInternal(String appId, Type type, IApplicationHost appHost, Boolean failIfExists, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObjectWithDefaultAppHostAndAppId(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type type, Boolean failIfExists, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, String& appId)
  at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.CreateHost()  StackTrace:
```

I tried to Assert that permission but it doesn't seem to solve it

In fact I think the AspNetHostingPermission is not the root cause (something else must be missing here)

What is weird is that this is a variation of the code that is executed by the aspnet_compiler.exe and that works

Comment: Did you perhaps omit some potentially relevant code from the above sample?  It doesn't look like it retrieves the ClientBuildManager.CodeGenDir value, which appears to be the trigger for the problem according to the stack trace.

Comment: The problem was caused by the need to run this code under admin privileges